# Mongoose custom virtual field return promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new in mongoDB, I have virtual field like this

```
videoSchema.virtual('playURL').get(async function () {
    return await getVideoURLbyId(this.video_id, true)
        .then(res => res)
})

videoSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })
videoSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true })
```

I can log the result but when show on browser, it shows empty result `playURL:{}`. How to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not possible use asynchronous in Virtual look this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1894), because `virtuals` are just getters/setters, which are assumed to be synchronous.  Use a custom [method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) instead